# Unable to access Magento admin or frontend: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1203] User already has more than 'max_user_connections'

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error, frontend

I am unable to access frontend or backend. The error is :

```
a:4:{i:0;s:108:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1203] User website_superuser already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections";i:1;s:2667:"#0     /home/website/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(55251): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /home/website/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(55731): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /home/website/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(53923): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /home/website/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(54981): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /home/website/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(55839): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /home/website/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(30069): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /home/website/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(30010): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /home/website/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(12175): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /home/website/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(12205): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /home/website/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(12190): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /home/website/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(12215): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /home/website/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(32099): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection()
#12 /home/website/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(24135): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#13 /home/website/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(24167): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#14 /home/website/public_html/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#15 /home/website/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(5861): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#16 /home/website/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(5866): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#17 /home/website/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(21013): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#18 /home/website/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(20871): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#19 /home/website/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(20754): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#20 /home/website/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/website/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}";s:3:"url";s:85:"/index.php/admin/customer/index/key/417da801f7f6439703a68329d25cd222/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Answer (score 1):

It tells you what the problem is on the first line - you have too many active connections to your MySQL database.

A quick google search gave the following suggestions:

In your php ini file you can increase MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS and MAX_CONNECTIONS

Or you can try to use this SQL command:

```
GRANT ALL * TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 1000;
```

[Source](http://www.question2answer.org/qa/18513/already-max_user_connections-active-connections-include)

There is another thread on Stackoverflow where someone had the same error. You can read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079531/mysqli-error-user-already-has-more-than-max-user-connections-active-connectio)